# I want WordPress gravity form upload file validation before submission

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

Actually I want a pre-validation that when a user uploads a wrong file extension rather than a pdf file in WordPress gravity form than before submitting the form it should show the error that the file is wrong it should be PDF.

I use ajax="true" in gravity form shortcode its also a good option because the page is not refreshed in ajax=" true" but I want a pre-validation that when a user uploads a wrong file extension rather than a pdf file in WordPress gravity form than before submitting the form it should show the error that the file is wrong it should be PDF.

`[gravityform id=5 title=false description=false ajax=true tabindex=49]`

I already try this code but I want a pre-validation that when a user uploads a wrong file extension it shows error before submission

Answer (score 0):

You should look at their hooks

https://docs.gravityforms.com/category/developers/hooks/

Comment: Thanks for your quick response but I already read the docs etc but I did not find the proper solution that when a user uploads a wrong file extension rather than a pdf file in WordPress gravity form than before submitting the form it should show the error that the file is wrong it should be PDF.